# Using pyserial for sending keystrokes

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a task where I have to send keystrokes to a machine and to achieve the same I have two machine out of which one is Host Machine (running python scripts) and other is the target machine (where I have to send keystrokes). I am using "L3 Systems Inc's KeyAT device" on COM1.

Now the problem is I am unable to send keystrokes and following is the code I am running.

```
import serial, time

#initialization and open the port
#possible timeout values:
#    1. None: wait forever, block call
#    2. 0: non-blocking mode, return immediately
#    3. x, x is bigger than 0, float allowed, timeout block call

ser = serial.Serial()
#ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.port = "COM1"
#ser.port = "/dev/ttyS2"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
#ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 1            #non-block read
#ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read
ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
ser.writeTimeout = 2     #timeout for write

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():
    try:
        ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output 
                     #and discard all that is in buffer
        #write data
        # ser.write("AT+CSQ")
        ser.write("~~~~~~~~~~\r")
        ser.write("~:04\r")
        # ser.write('\x03')

        #print("write data: AT+CSQ")
        time.sleep(0.5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data
        numOfLines = 0

        while True:
            response = ser.readline()
            print("read data: " + response)
            numOfLines = numOfLines + 1
            if (numOfLines >= 5):
                break
        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Can anyone please help

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: So, you're saying you are "unable to send". What happens? An exception? Nothing at all? If you connect a terminal application (e.g. Putty) to COM1, does it work as expected?

Comment: Well It doesn't throw any error or exception..it jsut execute with no response..and also I haven't tried it with putty yet

Comment: Try Putty first. If that doesn't work there is no point trying to debug. Then try read() instead of readline(), just to avoid issues with line endings.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is the ser.readline() returns binary , you need transform it into string: str(response), so it will work perfectly!